# How can I make my macro shortcut key work again?

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I created a macro to format the header of my spreadsheets, and I assigned the macro the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+H". It initially worked fine, but now the shortcut key has ceased to be recognized. I can still run the macro if I go to the macro dialog or into the VBA editor; it's just that the shortcut key no longer works.

I did change the name of the module in the VBA editor, but have verified that the new name is referenced in the macro dialog in Excel. I've even deleted the shortcut key and re-assigned it since the name change.

I can create a new macro with shortcut key and the new macro's shortcut key works.

Any advice on how to get the header macro's shortcut key to work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider using `Application.OnKey` to force Excel to run a specific macro for a given key combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who've responded. After digging into this a bit further, myself, I discovered that the macro was named oddly in the "Macro name" dialog. It was listed as "PERSONAL.XLSB!StandardHeader.StandardHeader". I don't know when it renamed itself with the additional ".StandardHeader"; none of the rest of the macros have a period or information after that. After noticing it, though, I was able to rename the Sub, which fixed both the naming and the shortcut key issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign macro shortcuts by going to the “Developer” tab and opening the “Macros” dialog. Here, select the macro, click “Options” and then choose your shortcut. That should work.

[image: Assign macro shortcuts]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Michael. That's the method I used when I mentioned that I had tried deleting the shortcut key, then re-assigning it...to no avail.

Comment: That weird. Once you registered the shortcut in the way I described and then reopen the dialog box - does it still show up or is the shortcut key just blank?

Comment: Still shows up. I did, however, notice that in the "Macro name" dialog it was listed as "PERSONAL.XLSB!StandardHeader.StandardHeader". I don't know when it renamed itself with the additional period and name after that. After noticing it, though, I was able to rename the Sub, which fixed both the naming and the shortcut key issue.